# Diferencias al ejecutar una función?

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos expresiones funcionales, cuál es la diferencia entre encerrarla entre parentesis y llamarla versus solo llamarla?

**Sin paréntesis:**

```
var it = (function(){})();
```

**Con paréntesis:**

```
var it = function(){}();
```

**Cuál es la diferencia entre ambas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una [expresión de función](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) puede ser ejecutada inmediatamente:

```
var FNexpression=function() { console.log('ejecutada FNexpression'); }();
// ejecutada FNexpression
```

Una [declaración de función](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) en cambio no puede ser inmediatamente ejecutada

```
function FNdeclaration() { console.log('ejecutada FNdeclaration'); }();
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Pero puedes ejecutarla igual si la envuelves en paréntesis, porque entonces se trata como si fuera una expresión de función.

```
(function FNdeclaration() { console.log('ejecutada FNdeclaration'); })();
// ejecutada FNdeclaration
```

Linters como [ESLint](https://eslint.or), por defecto te corrigen lo anterior

> error Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function

sugiriendo que el estilo correcto es:

```
(function FNdeclaration() { console.log('ejecutada FNdeclaration'); } () );
```

Que funciona igual que lo anterior pero al parecer es una convención más entendible.

Y como dijo Tygreton, este patrón se conoce como **IIFE** (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), o sea una función que se autoejecuta apenas es definida.

Answer (score 4):

Las funciones que utilizan esta sintaxis se denominan **funciones autoejecutables**.

```
var it = (function(){})();
```

Una vez declaradas, se llaman a sí mismas para ejecutarse estando entonces disponibles desde otras partes de la aplicación.

Si la función *devuelve un objeto* este pasa a formar parte del **contexto global**.

```
(function () {
  console.log('Esta función no tiene nombre y se ejecutara inmediatamente');
}());
```

También pueden recibir **parámetros** con la siguiente sintaxis

```
(function(param1){
  // ... code ...
})(param1);
```